# Fill missing time slots for multiple users

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to fill the missing slots in the CSV file which has date and time as a string.

My input is:

```
time_slot              User       Location
2017-10-26 00:00:00      1           156 
2017-10-26 10:00:00      1           55
2017-10-26 12:00:00      1           848
2017-10-27 02:00:00      1           79
2017-10-27 16:00:00      1           846
2017-10-27 23:00:00      1           648
2017-10-26 00:00:00      2           75
2017-10-26 02:00:00      2           32
2017-10-26 10:00:00      2           18
2017-10-27 01:00:00      2           874
2017-10-27 04:00:00      2           46
2017-10-27 18:00:00      2           96
2017-10-26 07:00:00      3           25
2017-10-26 09:00:00      3           463
2017-10-26 14:00:00      3           85
2017-10-27 06:00:00      3           95
2017-10-27 23:00:00      3           12
```

Output should be

```
time_slot              User       Location
2017-10-26 00:00:00      1           156
.
.
.
.
2017-10-26 09:00:00      1           156 
2017-10-26 10:00:00      1           55
2017-10-26 11:00:00      1           55
2017-10-26 12:00:00      1           848
.
.          848 for all slots in between
.
2017-10-26 24:00:00      1           848
.
.           848

2017-10-27 02:00:00      1           79
.
.          79
.

2017-10-27 16:00:00      1           846

             846
Same as above

2017-10-27 23:00:00      1           648
2017-10-26 00:00:00      2           75
2017-10-26 02:00:00      2           32
2017-10-26 10:00:00      2           18
2017-10-27 01:00:00      2           874
2017-10-27 04:00:00      2           46
2017-10-27 18:00:00      2           96
2017-10-26 07:00:00      3           25
2017-10-26 09:00:00      3           463
2017-10-26 14:00:00      3           85
2017-10-27 06:00:00      3           95
2017-10-27 23:00:00      3           12
```

the datetime frequency is 1hour. Instead of filling 0 in the missing slots we fill the location point of the previous timeslots

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use  [`DataFrame.asfreq`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.asfreq.html) in [`DataFrame.groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html):

```
df1 = (df.groupby('User')['Location']
        .apply(lambda x: x.asfreq(freq='H',method='ffill'))
        .reset_index())
print (df1.head(10))
   User           time_slot  Location
0     1 2017-10-26 00:00:00       156
1     1 2017-10-26 01:00:00       156
2     1 2017-10-26 02:00:00       156
3     1 2017-10-26 03:00:00       156
4     1 2017-10-26 04:00:00       156
5     1 2017-10-26 05:00:00       156
6     1 2017-10-26 06:00:00       156
7     1 2017-10-26 07:00:00       156
8     1 2017-10-26 08:00:00       156
9     1 2017-10-26 09:00:00       156
```

**Detail**:

```
print (df.index)
DatetimeIndex(['2017-10-26 00:00:00', '2017-10-26 10:00:00',
               '2017-10-26 12:00:00', '2017-10-27 02:00:00',
               '2017-10-27 16:00:00', '2017-10-27 23:00:00',
               '2017-10-26 00:00:00', '2017-10-26 02:00:00',
               '2017-10-26 10:00:00', '2017-10-27 01:00:00',
               '2017-10-27 04:00:00', '2017-10-27 18:00:00',
               '2017-10-26 07:00:00', '2017-10-26 09:00:00',
               '2017-10-26 14:00:00', '2017-10-27 06:00:00',
               '2017-10-27 23:00:00'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns]', name='time_slot', freq=None)
```

Comment: Sorry for the trouble. There is no 24:00. The time is from  00 to 23.

Comment: @Krush23 - No problem, now it is simplier

Comment: How can we set range for the date, Ex: If we have 7 days of data and I need only 3days and the frequency is 15 minutes timeslots.

Comment: @Krush23 - 3 days are specify by dates like `L = ['2017-10-25','2017-10-26','2017-10-27']` or by monday, tuesday, thursday? Or different?

Comment: They are dates like 2017-10-25.

Comment: @Krush23 - then use `L = ['2017-10-25','2017-10-26']
df = df[df.index.floor('d').isin(pd.to_datetime(L))]` and last `df = df.groupby('User')['Location'].apply(lambda x: x.asfreq(freq='15Min', method='ffill')).reset_index()`